# visual studio 2010 setup project - why can't create empty folder?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

Im trying to create empty folder in application folder. I created a folder in Setup project, but when im installing, the folder is not being created. I assume its because its empty. Is there a way to create it still/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Visual Studio setup project will not allow you to create empty folder. Instead of visual studio you can try to create setup project using [WIX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/). 
Its free and more scalable compared to Visual studio setup project.

Comment: @eddyuk , the answer regarding AlwaysCreate properties is the correct answer. This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 11):

Right click on the folder, select properties window, set AlwaysCreate property true. that's it. No need to create set up file with any other s/w. Visual Studio is Microsoft product.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the AlwaysCreate Property of the folder to true.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to create an (empty) textfile in the folder.
It's not nice, but it works.
I am thankful for any hints to find a better solution.

Comment: I resolved that by checking option Always Create. It has to be true and then you don't need the file.